# Dynamic create ul li with array in Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I am trying to create a ul > li dynamically in jquery.

I have this data:

```
var nodeDataArray = [{
    key: 0,
    name: "George V"
}, {
    key: 1,
    parent: 0,
    name: "Edward VIII"
}, {
    key: 2,
    parent: 0,
    name: "George VI"
}, {
    key: 7,
    parent: 2,
    name: "Elizabeth II"
}];
```

My HTML structure is below:

```
<ul>
    <li>List 1
        <ul>
             <li>Sub List 1</li>
             <li>Sub List 2</li>
             <li>Sub List 3
                 <ul>
                     <li>Sub Sub List 1</li>
                     <li>Sub Sub List 2</li>
                     <li>Sub Sub List 3</li>
                     <li>Sub Sub List 4</li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 1</li>
</ul>
```

There are thousands of Ul > li which i want to create. I want some dynamic way like array or in loop to create these type of lists.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I want to insert data in this form

Comment: I want to insert data in this form..

[pre]var nodeDataArray = [
      { key: 0, name: "George V"},
        { key: 1, parent: 0, name: "Edward VIII"},
        { key: 2, parent: 0, name: "George VI"},
          { key: 7, parent: 2, name: "Elizabeth II"}
    ];[/pre]

and get it into the above UL LI format. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you could tell how you are going to get your dynamic data that would help. A better way for this would be to use a templating engine. Else you can use the following jquery method to build the html.

```
var output = [];
$.each(data, function(index,value){ // offcourse the data comes dynamically
    output.push("<ul><li>+value+</li></ul>"); 
});

$("#somediv").html(output.join(""));
```

This is not a concrete result, but will give u a heads' up.